# What's the difference between createPair and addLiquidity?

Tags: ethereum

`createPair` declare in Uniswap Factory contract, `addLiquidity` declared in Uniswap Router contract, both can create liquidity pair and swap avaliable in app.uniswap.org.

But most developers use `addLiquidity` instead of `createPair`. What's the difference between createPair and addLiquidity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the function naming suggests, both functions have a different purpose.

- `createPair()` is meant to be used mainly for creating a pair
- `addLiquidity()` is for adding liquidity to a pair

Having said that, `addLiquidity()` is more robust and [performs](https://github.com/Uniswap/v2-periphery/blob/master/contracts/UniswapV2Router02.sol#L43) a call to `createPair()` if the pair doesn't exist yet. So by calling `addLiquidity()` you can "create a pair and add liquidity" in one transaction, instead of splitting the action into 2 separate transactions, saving transaction fees.